# Are car repair questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

Are questions regarding car repair on topic?

If it's truly just DIY I'd say yes, but if it's just home improvement I guess no.

Answer (score 13):

The site has been defined as 'Home improvement', so I would say car questions are off topic.

Comment: I concur - there's a completely separate site in the commitment phase for auto repair.

Comment: Yeah go commit to it so we can get it going :)

Comment: Agreed.  Can't wait until we have a different name... the "diy" subdomain confuses people I think. =)